# Eigen code fail in release mode but work in debug mode

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, odroid

Hi everyone who use Eigen, I encountered a strange question here.

I implemented a Unscented Kalman Filter with [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

It works very well on my PC, but the same piece of code will generate segmentation fault on my embedded system, [Odroid XU](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G137510300620) (Armv7 Architecture).

After hours of debugging, I found the problem was with this part:

```
qrSolver.compute(OS.transpose());    
m_q=qrSolver.householderQ();
m_r = qrSolver.matrixQR().triangularView<Upper>();

S_pre = m_r.block(0,0,n,n).transpose();

if (w_c0 < 0)
    internal::llt_inplace<float,Upper>::rankUpdate(S_pre,
                sqrt(-w_c0)*(sigmaPoints.col(0) - state_pre),
    -1);
else
    internal::llt_inplace<float,Upper>::rankUpdate(S_pre,
                sqrt(w_c0)*(sigmaPoints.col(0) - state_pre),
    1);
```

where I first compute the QR decomposition of matrix **OS** (dimension n-by-3n), and then perform rank update of its R component (dimension n-by-n). **internal::llt_inplace::rankUpdate** is a function in Eigen library which is not documented. It just perform rank-1 update to its first argument. This function can be found in ~/path_to_Eigen/Cholesky/LLT.h

The most strange thing of this piece of code is, with **-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug** it works perfectly, while if I compile with **-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release**, this code fails.

I would like to ask can anyone understand this or does anyone have similar issue before. Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: It could be possible that running debug results in extra checks which make it run correctly..

Comment: What if you disable NEON vectorization? (-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE) Can you run valgrind on your system? (you might also try your code with valgrind on your P, even if it's working there might be hidden errors).